# DB2: How to timely delete records

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a table in DB2 database that has a few columns, one of which is L_TIMESTAMP. The need is to delete records where difference between L_TIMESTAMP and CURRENT TIMESTAMP is greater than 5 minutes. This check needs to happen every hour. Please let me know if there is an approach to accomplish this at the DB end rather than scheduling a cron job at the appserver end.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=db2+scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The administrative task scheduler in DB2 would be a good way to accomplish this.  You need to wrap the DELETE statement in a stored procedure, then submit it to the scheduler.  The syntax for defining the schedule is based on cron but it is all handled inside DB2.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0054380.html

Comment: This would certainly work, but I would exercise some caution given the relatively frequent changes in direction IBM has shown for handling scheduled tasks and perhaps stick to cron or Task Scheduler if you're on Windows.